# Swift tableview Design

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

So i want to make some profile and in the profile theres a bunch of data obviously and i want to make like this, im still learning on swift so how do i make this? i know it using tableview but is that mean i need 2 cell instead of 1 or how? and how can i make this with storyboard.

[image]

i want to make the ui of the profile like this, so its like theres section for language and section for account and so on. thanks for any help i really appreciate that.

Comment: Better approach is to take tableview and use section for title like :- language, support, account ,
and a single cell for showing section's data.

Comment: okayy thanks for your tip im currently working on that im surfing the web for that tableview section kinda stuff @AnkurPurwar

Comment: If you need any help regarding this , then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I can point you to the right direction:

- In Storyboard, Add a UITableView inside your UIViewController
- Make your ViewController class the dataSource and delegate of this UITableView
- Then, inside your ViewController class, you can implement `numberOfSection`, `numberOfRows(in section: Int)` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
- You can name your sections in the delegate method `titleForSection(section: Int)` or by providing your own UIView in `headerViewForSection(section: Int)`
- In your image, I can see the sections being language, account and support.
- For the design of the cells: You could do that directly in storyboard by adding one or more prototype cells to your UITableView. For the language section for example, you could add a single prototype cell which contains two buttons. One for the "English" selection and one for the "Bahasa" selection.
- The top part of your image, containing the user profile image and "Invite your friends" could either be a larger UITableViewCell or more likely the `headerView` of the UITableView.

The design of most cells can be accomplished using standard UITableViewCells. They have a `textLabel`, a `detailLabel`and an `accessoryView`. Iirc, you can even specify the color of the `accessoryView` to make it as green as in your example image.

Comment: ahhh thanks for the direction i can know how to do it properly, thanks mate